# Ретинизация и адаптивность изображений

Tags: html, веб-программирование, адаптивная-верстка, img, адаптивность

Всем добрый день.
Проблема следующая:

Есть адаптивный сайт. 
В нем блок с картинкой.

По ТЗ необходимо картинки ретинизировать и при этом на каждом вьюпорте (мобила, планшет, десктоп) картинка меняется.
Так же в **теге picture можно использовать только webp формат картинок.**
Соответственно, стандартный формат (jpg) должен меняться при ретине или изменении вьюпорта именно в img, не в picture.

Нашла способ с srcset и sizes.
Но валидатор ругался, если я в srscet добавляла и ретиновую картинку 2x и картинку конкретного вьюпорта (например, 768w).

Как мне сделать и ретинизацию картинки и её изменение при трех видах вьюпорта?

```
<picture>
                <source type="image/webp" media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="img/croatia-mobile@1x.webp 1x, img/croatia-mobile@2x.webp 2x">
                <source type="image/webp" media="(max-width: 1023px)" srcset="img/croatia-tablet@1x.webp 1x, img/croatia-tablet@2x.webp 2x">
                <source type="image/webp" srcset="img/croatia-desktop@1x.webp 1x, img/croatia-desktop@2x.webp 2x">
                <img class="places__img" srcset="img/croatia-desktop@1x.jpg 1x,
                                                img/croatia-desktop@2x.jpg 2x,
                                                img/croatia-desktop@1x.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 1023px) 288px" src="img/croatia-desktop@1x.jpg" alt="Хорватия" width="350" height="430">
              </picture>
```